# Passing parameters to Java method through JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

In Java, in the calling class, there is a method

```
public void test(int i)
{...
```

that I would like to call from a C++ method, so I tried

```
jobject obj = env->AllocObject(cls);
jmethodID testID = env->GetMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V");
if (testID)
{
    const jint val = 15;
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, testID, val);
}
```

If test does not take an argument and the signature in GetMethodID is "()V" this works fine, but with the int (or any other type), it generates a PID log file complaining of an internal NoSuchMethodException in GetMethodID.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

PS I gave up, but don't know how to mark a question as closed.

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example that can be used to reproduce the issue. The only thing I see in that snippet that is out of the ordinary is your use of `AllocObject` instead of `NewObject`, but I don't see why that would affect resolving methods on the class.

Comment: Wild guessing: could it be that your native code accesses an old version of your Java code (from when you tried without arguments)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In the meantime, I have given up on this approach and achieved the same thing in a different way. It can remain as one of life's many mysteries.